# I need help creating a bar chart in excel

Tags: excel, charts

I need to create a bar chart in exel that will show the average sale values of two stores during a three month period.

| Breakfast Layout | No | No | No | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| month | jan | feb | mar | jan | feb | mar |
| Site | SCCM | SCCM | SCCM | SCUP | SCUP | SCUP |
| Average Sale | 181,192 | 139,093 | 199,034 | 130,203 | 99,293 | 102,103 |

The graph should look like this:
[image]

I don't have much knowledge in creating charts in Office but I tried a bunch of times to just use a template and change some values since yesterday but i haven't had much luck.

Any help to get to the example picture would be much appreciated.

Thank you!

**[Adding some information, i need to group the Yes and No columns per month so that it's clear to read. And have them both displayed in a different color.]**

Comment: Structure the data as JAN Yes No, FEB Yes No, MAR Yes No, then it will display as you show.

Answer (score 0):

Change the layout of your data as shown in the screenshot here below. Your bar chart should then automatically set up in your desired format. With a bit of manual adjustments to the chart's style you can make it look pretty much exactly as in your example:

[image]